# How to add a page number in the header of a PDF file using iText7 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext7

I can't adding the page numbers in the `header` on my pdf document using `iText7` and `C#`. ...

this is the tutorial
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/page-numbers-and-pdf-a

the error is on these lines when I add on my code this part after closed document

```
    int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
            .Format("page " + i + " of " + n))
            .SetFontSize(8)
            .SetMarginLeft(20),
           559, 806, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT,
           VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0);
    }
```

I don't know why but this happens when I insert a new page in the pdf document

```
 document.Add(new AreaBreak());
```

How to do resolve this?

My code as follow.

```
private class TableHeaderEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    private Table table;
    private float tableHeight;
    private Document doc;

    public TableHeaderEventHandler(Document doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
        InitTable();

        TableRenderer renderer = (TableRenderer)table.CreateRendererSubTree();
        renderer.SetParent(new DocumentRenderer(doc));

        LayoutResult result = renderer.Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, PageSize.A4)));
        tableHeight = result.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight();
    }

    public void HandleEvent(Event currentEvent)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)currentEvent;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();

        int pageNum = docEvent.GetDocument().GetPageNumber(page);

        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize();
        float coordX = pageSize.GetX() + doc.GetLeftMargin();
        float coordY = pageSize.GetTop() - doc.GetTopMargin();
        float width = pageSize.GetWidth() - doc.GetRightMargin() - doc.GetLeftMargin();
        float height = GetTableHeight();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(coordX, coordY, width, height);

        new Canvas(canvas, rect)
            .Add(table)
            .Close();

        int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
               .Format("page " + i + " of " + n))
                .SetFontSize(8)
                .SetMarginLeft(20),
               559, 806, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT,
               VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0);
        }
    }

    public float GetTableHeight()
    {
        return tableHeight;
    }

    private void InitTable()
    {
        Paragraph newline = new Paragraph(new Text("\n"));

        table = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();

        Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory
        .Create(@"C:\\Users\\admin\\source\\repos\\newpdf2\\newpdf2\\img\\logo.png"))
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        img.ScaleToFit(150, 150);
        table.AddCell(img).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens? You say an error occurs. Which error? With which stack trace? And how do you register your `TableHeaderEventHandler`?

Comment: @mkl thanks for reply, solved with iText KB